# Django - How to dynamically create signals inside model Mixin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm working on a model `Mixin` which needs to dynamically set signals based on one attribute.

It's more complicated but for simplicity, let's say the Mixin has this attribute:

```
models = ['app.model1','app.model2']
```

This attribute is defined in `model` which extends this mixin.

How can I register signals dynamically?

I tried to create a classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def set_signals(cls):
    def status_sig(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        print('SIGNAL')
        ... do som things

    for m in cls.get_target_models():
        post_save.connect(status_sig,m)
```

My idea was to call this method somewhere in class automatically (for example `__call__` method) but for now, I just tried to call it and then `save` the model to see if it works but it didn't.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

print(post_save.receivers)
Realestate.set_signals()
print(post_save.receivers)

r = Realestate.objects.first()
r.status = 1
r.save()
```

**output**

```
[]
[((139967044372680, 46800232), <weakref at 0x7f4c9d702408; dead>), ((139967044372680, 46793464), <weakref at 0x7f4c9d702408; dead>)]
```

So you see that it registered those models but no signal has been triggered after saving the realestate.

Do you know how to make it work? Even better without having to call method explicitely?

EDIT:

I can't just put the signals creation inside `mixin` file because models depends on the string in child model.

Comment: the `sender` attribute of the `signals.connect()` method must be a Python object, is `get_target_models()` returning the classes or the strings?

Comment: and also i don't understand your last edit, why this cannot be in the mixing. If `get_target_models()` is using `cls.models`, it'll get the ones set in the child classes.

Comment: @dirkgroten get_target_models() returns a list of model classes, not strings.

Comment: @dirkgroten It can't be in file outside the class because signals can be created after interpreter knows the "models" attribute which is defined in child class (the class that uses the mixin)

Comment: it depends where you call `set_signals`.

Comment: @dirkgroten just to test if it works, I called it before saving realestate. Check the last snippet - it's django shell. In real world I want it to be called just once when django starts.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already solved this:

In the `connect` method, set `weak=False`. By default it's `True` so the locally-defined function reference will get lost if the object instance is garbage collected.

This is likely what's happening to your `status_sig` function; as you can see in the print out of the `post_save` receivers, the `weakref`'s are dead so will always just return `None`

In the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal.connect):

> weak – Django stores signal handlers as weak references by default. Thus, if your receiver is a local function, it may be garbage collected. To prevent this, pass weak=False when you call the signal’s connect() method.

For more info on `weakref`s, see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html)